# How to access specific superpixel in opencv C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am writing a program in C++ using superpixels in opencv and I really need to be able to access specific pixels (In particular, to iterate through every superpixel in the image), I am using the built in superpixel segmentation in the opencv extra module 'opencv2/ximgproc.hpp'.

Here is extracts of my code that are to do with superpixel segmentation:

```
/* preceding code */

int num_iterations = 6;
int prior = 2;
bool double_step = false;
int num_superpixels = 200;
int num_levels = 4;
int num_histogram_bins = 5;

bool init = false;

Mat result, mask;
Ptr<SuperpixelSEEDS> seeds;
int display_mode = 0;

/* Unrelated code... */
while(true) // Feed in video data
{
    if(!init)
    {
        seeds = createSuperpixelSEEDS(frame.size().width, frame.size().height, frame.channels(), num_superpixels, num_levels, prior, num_histogram_bins, double_step);
        init = true;
    }

    seeds->iterate(frame,num_iterations);
    seeds->getLabelContourMask(mask,false);

    /* More unrelated code... */

    Mat labels;
    seeds->getLabels(labels);

    /* End of superpixel code */
}
```

The documentation isn't helping me at all and I really need to access each superpixel specifically, preferably by some sort of label.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

With [`getLabels`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/da0/classcv_1_1ximgproc_1_1SuperpixelLSC.html#a7bae78ae26432f278ce7ed33cdb057a9) you get a `CV_32SC1` (`Mat_<int>`) image where the pixels belonging to the same superpixel have the same value. The labels are in the range `[0, getNumberOfSuperpixels()].`

So you can easily access each superpixel individually iterating over the label values, and creating the corresponding mask:

```
//...
Mat labels;
seeds->getLabels(labels);

int N = seeds->getNumberOfSuperpixels();
for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) 
{
    Mat1b mask_for_ith_sp = (labels == i);

    // Now you have the mask of the i-th superpixel.
    // You can do whatever you want with it.
    //...
}
```